# what am i missing?

Tags: equation-solving

An attempt to solve

```
FindRoot[
{
  0.8*p*((y^0.2)⁄(x^0.2))+x ((x-2))⁄((x-1)^2)==0
 ,0.2*p*((x^0.8)⁄(y^0.8))+y ((y-2))⁄((y-1)^2)==0
 ,0.8*p*((y1^0.2)⁄(x1^0.2))+x1 ((x1-4))⁄((x1-2)^2)==0
 ,0.2*p*((x1^0.8)⁄(y1^0.8))+y1 ((y1-4))⁄((y1-2)^2)==0
 ,6*p^-2==x^0.8y^0.2+x1^0.8y1^0.2
 ,0≤x≤0.999
 ,0≤y≤0.999
 ,0≤x1≤1.999
 ,0≤y1≤1.999
 ,0≤p
},{{x,0.1},{y,0.1},{x1,0.1},{y1,0.1},{p,0.1}}]
```

has brought to:

> In the first argument
>
> ```
> {
>  ((-2+x) x)/(-1+x)2+(0.8 p y0.2)/x0.2==0
>  ,(0.2 p x0.8)/y0.8+((-2+y) y)/(-1+y)2==0
>  ,((-4+x1) x1)/(-2+x1)2+(0.8 p y10.2)/x10.2==0
>  ,(0.2 p x10.8)/y10.8+((-4+y1) y1)/(-2+y1)2==0
>  ,6/p2==x0.8 y0.2+x10.8 y10.2
>  ,0<=x<=0.999
>  ,0<=y<=0.999
>  ,0<=x1<=1.999
>  ,0<=y1<=1.999
>  ,0<=p
> }
> ```
>
> only some of the components are equations. >>

Yet, Excel straight returns solution `{0.393085,0.236113,0.786171,0.472226,2.373604}`.
  I need your help to understand what’s wrong with it.

Comment: Did you mean "divide" where you've used the symbol "⁄"? If so, you should use the true forward-slash "/" instead.

Comment: First, you should not include inequalities into your list of equation. Second, you have four equations with 5 unknowns.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is exactly as stated: you've given it some inequalities rather than equations. The appropriate syntax is:

```
FindRoot[
 {
  0.8*p*((y^0.2)/(x^0.2)) + x ((x - 2))/((x - 1)^2) == 0, 
  0.2*p*((x^0.8)/(y^0.8)) + y ((y - 2))/((y - 1)^2) == 0, 
  0.8*p*((y1^0.2)/(x1^0.2)) + x1 ((x1 - 4))/((x1 - 2)^2) == 0, 
  0.2*p*((x1^0.8)/(y1^0.8)) + y1 ((y1 - 4))/((y1 - 2)^2) == 0, 
  6*p^-2 == x^0.8 y^0.2 + x1^0.8 y1^0.2
 },
 {{x, 0.1, 0, 0.990},
  {y, 0.1, 0, 0.999},
  {x1, 0.1, 0, 1.999},
  {y1, 0.1, 0, 1.999},
  {p, 0.1, 0, Infinity}
 }]
```

`FindRoot` is still unable to find a solution.

`NSolve` and `Reduce` also can't find solutions, even when I rationalise the equations. In fact, you can see by substituting the first equation into the second (to eliminate $\frac{p}{5} \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^{1/5}$) that there are no solutions.

Comment: thanks a lot, appreciate your joke, works smoothly.

Comment: I don't appreciate my joke :P what joke did I make?

Comment: 'Of course, the initial specified search point for y1 is outside the allowed region'. {y1, 0.1, 0, 1.999} works well.

Comment: I might have gone mad, but in the code I copy-pasted into Mathematica, it specified `1 <= y1 <= 1.999`. That is quite possibly my own idiocy.

Comment: Fixed now! charactercharacter